Inline == and != operators removed from list iterators in gcc11
My compiler is updating to gcc11, and has started throwing errors for this code that was compiling before:
#include <list>
#include <map>

template < class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
struct cache_map
{
    public:
        //! The type of items in this cache_map
        typedef std::pair<const Key, T> value_type;
        
    private: 
        // list of pairs: (key, data): [lru] ---> [mru]
        typedef std::list<value_type> list_type;
        
        // map: key -> list_iter
        typedef std::map<Key, typename list_type::iterator, Compare> map_type;
        
        // An iterator implementation based on list_type::iterator.
        template<class Iterator>
        class iterator_impl : Iterator
        {
            friend class cache_map<Key, T, Compare>;
            typedef Iterator base;
            base& base_reference() { return static_cast<base&> (*this); }
            const base& base_reference() const { return static_cast<const base&> (*this); }
            
            public:
                using base::difference_type;
                using base::iterator_category;
                using base::value_type;
                using base::pointer;
                using base::reference;
                using base::operator*;
                using base::operator->;
                
                template<class I>
                iterator_impl(iterator_impl<I> i) : base(i.base_reference()) { }
                explicit iterator_impl(const base& i) : base(i) {}
                iterator_impl() : base() { }
                
                template<class I>
                bool operator==(const iterator_impl<I>& other) const
                {
                    return base::operator== (other.base_reference ());
                }
                
                template<class I>
                bool operator!=(const iterator_impl<I>& other) const
                {
                    return base::operator!= (other.base_reference ());
                }
            
        }
    public:
        //! An iterator for the range [lru] ---> [mru].
        typedef iterator_impl<typename list_type::iterator> iterator;
        
        //! An iterator for the range [lru] ---> [mru].
        typedef iterator_impl<typename list_type::const_iterator> const_iterator;
}

The error message complains that != isn't a member of iterator_impl: error: 'operator!=' is not a member of 'cache_map<int, bool>::iterator_impl<std::_List_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, bool> > >::base' If I remove the != operator, I get the same thing for the == operator.
I saw that this gcc commit removed the inline == and != operators for list iterators (lines 342-353). I assume this is why I'm getting an error, because my code is trying to use the operators from base, which is an alias of the std::list iterator type. The code compiles when I change it to manually make the == and != comparisons, as shown below:
                template<class I>
                bool operator==(const iterator_impl<I>& other) const
                {
                    return this->base_reference() == other.base_reference ();
                }
                
                template<class I>
                bool operator!=(const iterator_impl<I>& other) const
                {
                    return this->base_reference() != other.base_reference ();
                }

My question is, is this a bug in gcc11? It seems like it may have been an accident to remove the operators without adding them back.

C++20 removed operators == and != from many std types replacing them with <=>

The bug seems to be in previous gcc versions return base::operator== (other.base_reference ()); would be not valid because the operator== at always been indicated as non-member in C++ specifications.
